# Write to web text file

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am programming in Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express.
I have a text file in a folder on my web server containing one character: '0'.
When I start my C# Application I want to read the number from my text file, increase it by 1, and then save the new number instead.

I've browsed the web but I can't find a good answer. All I get is questions and answers about writing/reading from local text files.

So basically, I want to write some text to a text file which is not on my computer but here:
http://mywebsite.xxx/something/something/myfile.txt

Is this possible?

Comment: Or do you have a desktop application and you're trying to write the text file to a directory on another server?

Comment: Who down voted the OP?

Comment: I guess the code writing to the text file on your Server should be on the Server, a remote application can only send some request to do so.

Comment: I'm a beginner programmer and not sure about what ASP.Net is. I thought it had something with websites to do. The program I've created is running on your computer, and it uses the internet only to search for updates (this is working) and to log how many times the program has been started (this is not working).

Comment: So, just to be clear, you are running a desktop application that "phones home" to a web server application whose job it is to track how many times the desktop application has contacted the web server. Correct?

Comment: Yes, but I don't really have an application on the server, just a regular .txt file

Comment: If you have a web server it does not support such interaction by itself. If it would, then anybody could write to your file. How did you put the .txt on the server? Through FTP? You can make your application create a temporary file containing the desired values, and then upload through FTP (or WebDav, if you have that access), but I wouldn't recommend, it's a better solution (if your server supports that) to write any kind of application or script that runs on the server, and updates the uploaded file upon request. All the similar solutions work like this.

Comment: @BartaTamás Thank you for the information you provided. The File Transfer Protocol I'm using is FileZilla. Is it possible to start a PHP application via my C# application?

Comment: Yes, you have to issue a HTTP request to the PHP file, and if your server is configured well, it runs the PHP script. (You can of course try PHP frameworks to build a whole PHP application, but a simple script is easier, and enough.)

Comment: Are you certain that you want to allow the program to arbitrarily change a file on your ftp site? That means that anyone could write anything to that file (as long as they have the username/password, which they do if they're running your program and can sniff packets) including lower numbers, text, or whatever they want. If not, it'd be much better for you to run a server-side application that does the changing for you.

Comment: @MichaelTodd My program is not used by many, and the numbers are not that important. It wouldn't be very dramatic if someone changed the text file. If it's possible, I would like to learn how to do it. I would also like to learn it the way you say is the best, but I don't know any other language than C# yet. My brother, however, knows PHP, Javascript, and CSS. Maybe I should learn some of those. But that will be a later project, I think...

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution, using File Transport Protocol as Barta Tamás mentioned.
However, I learned from Michael Todd that this is not safe, so I will not use it in my own application, but maybe it can be helpful to someone else.

I found information about uploading files using FTP here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715.aspx

```
    void CheckNumberOfUses()
    {
        // Get the objects used to communicate with the server.
        FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://mywebsite.xx/public_html/something1/something2/myfile.txt");
        HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://mywebsite.xx/something1/something2/myfile.txt");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
        Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        string tempString = null;
        int count = resStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        if (count != 0)
        {
            tempString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, count);
            int numberOfUses = int.Parse(tempString) + 1;
            sb.Append(numberOfUses);
        }

        ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

        // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
        ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("login", "password");

        // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
        byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
        ftpRequest.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;
        Stream requestStream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
        requestStream.Close();
        FtpWebResponse ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
        ftpResponse.Close();
    }
```

Read in the comments of the question how this can be done better, not using FTP. My solution is **not** suggested if you have important files on your server.

Answer (score 3):

You may have to adjust the path directory, but this works:

```
    string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile) + "\\something\\myfile.txt";
    string previousNumber = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
    int newNumber;
    if (int.TryParse(previousNumber, out newNumber))
    {
        newNumber++;
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path, 1024))
        {
            Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(newNumber.ToString());
            fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
        }
    }
```